# does uncommenting works to install PHP extension

Tags: php

this is not a bug in my program but a general doubt. I've heard and read that in Windows people uncomment extension names in PHP.ini to enable them. Does this works in Ubuntu too?

Actually I've tried it in my Ubuntu and it didn't work, just want to be sure it doesn't works like this in Ubuntu or it was my fault somewhere (which doesn't matters now ).

In my case I didn't even touched the ini file but just recompiled the php from source with passing extension arguments. Why didn't I have to enable them?

Tried searching SO but didn't find any questions related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Windows, pretty much all the extensions are already compiled as DLLs. So when you uncomment the line in the ini file and restart the service, it simply loads the file.

When you compile from source in Linux, you aren't building all the extensions by default. You usually have to explicitly specify which extensions you want to enable and they are compiled along with PHP. So the extension has to be compiled successfully and be accessible to be used. The ini file is simply the instruction of whether or not to TRY loading that extension when PHP starts.

Also, there are some basic extensions that are part of the typical PHP build / configure / make process. You can consult the docs to figure out which ones are default but a good practice is to explicitly enable those that you want.

Don't build EVERY extension if you don't need them though. The more extensions that get loaded, the more memory that PHP needs/uses when starting up.

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer is yes it works but if only the extension is in your ubuntu.

Comment: I've updated my question, can you please check and explain a bit more about it?